# How can I verify that a TCP packet has received an ACK in JAVA?

Tags: java-me

After sending some tcp data by any method (mine is below)

```
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
outToServer.writeBytes(string);
```

How can I verify in JAVA that TCP data is sent successfully? OR is there any way of reading the ACK received (from tcpserver) ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Operating systems typically does not expose this to applications.

If you need to know whether data has made it to the other end, you need to implement acks at your application protocol, not at the transport level that TCP concerns itself with.

Comment: Thanx nos actually I am trying to calculate upload speed in this application. I am sending a TCP message of specific size and then using timers to calculate the upload speed. Now when i send the message the code exits without checking that either the message has successfully reveived at server.   

can u help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

I always use Wireshark to debug TCP apps. It is a TCP tracing tool that shows you the individual packets with their acks, retransmits etc.

It is not in code, but it does allow you to double check the behavior of your app.

Check [wireshark.](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: thank you Joon. I am already using wireshark but the thing is i need to know the about the ack  in code because i m calculating the time taken by a packet to reach server. and for that i need to know either it is received at server successfully or not. Is there any other way u can suggest me?